# pyspark add new column field with the data frame row number

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Hy, I'm trying build a recommendation system with Spark

I have a data frame with users email and movie rating.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["aa@gmail.com",2,3],["aa@gmail.com",5,5],["bb@gmail.com",8,2],["cc@gmail.com",9,3]]), columns=['user','movie','rating'])

sparkdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df, samplingRatio=0.1)

           user movie rating
  aa@gmail.com     2      3
  aa@gmail.com     5      5
  bb@gmail.com     8      2
  cc@gmail.com     9      3
```

My first doubt it is, pySpark MLlib doesn't accept emails I'm correct? Because this I need to change the email by a Primary key.

My approach was create a temporary table, select distinct user and now I want add a new column with a row number (and this number will be the primary key for each user.

```
sparkdf.registerTempTable("sparkdf")

DistinctUsers = sqlContext.sql("Select distinct user FROM sparkdf")
```

What I have

```
+------------+
|        user|
+------------+
|bb@gmail.com|
|aa@gmail.com|
|cc@gmail.com|
+------------+
```

What I want

```
+------------+
|        user| PK
+------------+
|bb@gmail.com| 1
|aa@gmail.com| 2
|cc@gmail.com| 3
+------------+
```

Next I will do a join and obtain my final data frame to use in MLlib

```
user movie rating
  1     2      3
  1     5      5
  2     8      2
  3     9      3
```

Regards 
and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Primary keys with Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33102727/1560062) practically answers your question but in this particular case using `StringIndexer` could be a better choice:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="user", outputCol="user_id")
indexed = indexer.fit(sparkdf ).transform(sparkdf)
```