# how to add a Incremental column ID for a table in spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I'm working on a spark mllib algorithm. The dataset I have is in this form

Company":"XXXX","CurrentTitle":"XYZ","Edu_Title":"ABC","Exp_mnth":.(there are more values similar to these)

Im trying to raw code String values to Numeric values. So, I tried using zipwithuniqueID for unique value for each of the string values.For some reason I'm not able to save the modified dataset to the disk. Can I do this in any way using spark SQL? or what would be the better approach for this?

Comment: Sorry..I figured out with this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102727/primary-keys-with-apache-spark

Comment: Can you please delete your question (since it's a duplicate)? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primary keys with Apache Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102727/primary-keys-with-apache-spark)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Scala**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id
val dataFrame1 = dataFrame0.withColumn("index",monotonically_increasing_id())
```

**Java**

```
 Import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;
Dataset<Row> dataFrame1 = dataFrame0.withColumn("index",functions.monotonically_increasing_id());
```