# Hive auto increment UDF doesn't give desired results

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, udf

I am trying to create a `UDF` in `Hive`. This `UDF` has to auto increment a `hive` table column called `id`.

Now the following is the `Java` code to create the `UDF`.

```
package myudf;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFType;


@UDFType(deterministic = false, stateful = true)
public class autoincrement extends UDF{

      int lastValue;

    public int evaluate() {

     lastValue++;

        return lastValue;

   }

}
```

Now I am able create a jar file and add the jar file to hive like below:

```
add jar /home/cloudera/Desktop/increment.jar;
```

Then create a temporary function

```
create temporary function inc as 'myudf.autoincrement';
```

Create table like below.

```
Create table abc(id int, name string)
```

Insert values:

```
INSERT into TABLE abc SELECT inc() as id, 'Tim';
```

Do select statement:

```
select * from abc;
```

Output:

```
1  Tim
```

Insert values:

```
INSERT into TABLE abc SELECT inc() as id, 'John';
```

Do select statement:

```
select * from abc
```

Output:

```
1  Tim
1  John
```

But what I was expecting was when I insert values for the 2nd time.

My expected output was :

```
1  Tim
2  John
```

How to get the expected output. What should I change in the `Java` code to get the desired result?

And Can I use the same function in `Spark` as well

In spark when I do

```
sqlContext.sql("show functions")
```

It shows the list of all functions available in `Hive`

But when I do

```
sqlContext.sql("INSERT into TABLE abc SELECT inc() as id, 'Jim'")
```

I got the below error

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'undefined function inc; line 1 pos 29'
```

How to create the same `UDF` in `pyspark` and get the desired output

What happens when the insert statements are executed at the same time?

Comment: This isn't how UDF's work, a UDF can only know about the values its passed, you can't have a global state.

Comment: if you just need unique id you could use the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102727/primary-keys-with-apache-spark, otherwise you're going to have to do a sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps

1. change your insert to INSERT into TABLE abc SELECT max(id)+1 as id, 'Tim' from abc;
   or
2. Modify the UDF to take int column as input and return input+1
3. modify your insert to INSERT into TABLE abc SELECT inc(max(id)) as id, 'Tim' from abc;

You have to try the correctness of the SQL in hive as I have checked and it works in MYSQL.