# add additional row by index increasing for every line of row

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
ratings_test = test_data.map(lambda l: l.split()).map(lambda a : 
    Row(userId=int(a[0]),movieId=int(a[1]),index=i)).cache()
```

I want the index row to be increasing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primary keys with Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102727/primary-keys-with-apache-spark)

Comment: Use the zipWithIndex method on the RDD