# Spark SQL: Generate a row id column with auto increments in CONSECUTIVE integer

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a databricks notebook written in Scala. And I have this dataframe generated like this:

```
val df = spark.sql("SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName")
```

I want to add another column `RowID` that will automatically populate the rows with integers. I don't want to use the row_number() function. I need CONSECUTIVE integers starting from 1. Is there any other way?

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102727/primary-keys-with-apache-spark) but it does not help me to generate consecutive integers. And `monotonically_increasing_id` is not working for me. Is this function valid for databricks? Do we need to import some modules?

Thanks!

Comment: You can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37708553)

Comment: @mck that code is in python. any chance you can help me write it in Scala?